# How to change the style of the widgetContainer in the extLib

Tags: css, xpages, xpages-extlib

I am using the widgetContainer from the extension library. That works fine, but I want to style it differently (no oneUI).
So my problem. I can use the styleclass for the widget, but the widget creates some div's with it's own style's. They have no id so how can I catch/modify them?

```
<div id="view:_id1:_id5:_id44:_id45:_id46:wgNaviLeft" class="navWidget" style="border: solid thin black; padding:0px; margin: 2px;">
<div style="border-bottom: solid thin black; background-color:#DDDDDD"><span>main</span></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: you can use standard css selectors to get children or sibling nodes.

Comment: so why do you use widget? you can render divs and style them any way you want.

Comment: ok, what is the widgetContainer for? I want to use it as a pre-styled container (to display different stuff). The div and the span are created from the widgetContainer but I can't find a way to put a style on it. So maybe it is useless (at least in my case).